# Mercurial - get a list of files that were changed in the most recent changeset

Tags: mercurial, command

I know that `hg export tip` contains the above information. But the output contains more information than I need. Is there a way to get only the file names without parsing the output of `hg export tip`? Maybe some other mercurial command?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You want `status`, use it like this:

```
hg stat --change tip
```

That will list the file name of each file changed in the changeset tagged `tip` with a preceding `M` for modified, `R` for removed, or `A` for added.

You can replace `tip` with a tag or a revision number.

See more at `hg help status`

Comment: And if you want to look at the same revision that plain `hg export` uses (parent of the working directory) you can use `hg stat --change .` instead of `tip`.

Answer (score 3):

You can do this with templating as well.  See `hg help templating` for more info.

To get a list of only the files that changed in a revision:

```
hg log -r [rev] --template "{file_mods}\n"
```

In your case, replace `[rev]` with `tip`.  Using templates is sometimes more helpful than `status` when you need the information for batch processing (e.g. from a script) and don't want any other extraneous output.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:

```
$ hg diff | grep "^--- "
```

or,

```
$ hg diff -r 6755 | grep "^--- "
```

The `hg diff` will show you all the differences, and then the `grep` will weed out everything but the lines with the names of the changed files.  Yes, it does seem like a bit of a kludge, ... so don't tell anybody that I told you about it.